# How to insert hyperlinks in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to make Link Web / link info directory in C# where a user can save his links.

The following is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int i=0;
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.GridLines = true;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Links",250,HorizontalAlignment.Center );
    listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(textbox1.text);
    listview1.Items[i].subitems.add("textbox2.text")
}
```

`textbox2` contains the hyperlink but when I insert it displays as text, not as a hyperlink.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Is it that you expect `textbox2.text` to be replaced with the value of that element at runtime?

Comment: "textbox2.text" you are trying to add param as a text. Is it a control? And what kind of control is it?

Comment: i think you gave ans in WPF.. i want to ask that list view subitem only accept string to add but i want to add hyperlink in subitem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I display links in a ListView's detail mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288404/can-i-display-links-in-a-listviews-detail-mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView) -- an open source wrapper around a standard ListView. It supports links directly:

Also have a look at the DataGridView control which has support for LinkLabel.

Using this control, you get all the functionality of the details view in a ListView, but with more customisation per row.

Also you can set one property to true --> listView1.HotTracking = true; You code will look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(textbox1.Text);
        listView1.HotTracking = true;

        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("hyperlynk2.text");
    }
```

Comment: [Can I display links in a ListView's detail mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288404/can-i-display-links-in-a-listviews-detail-mode)

Comment: yes now i have tried but instead subitem link appear on main item as well. please also let me know that how can i open link in listview by clicking on it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288404/can-i-display-links-in-a-listviews-detail-mode try this post. The best choice as for me is using DataGridView control which has support for LinkLabel.